# Sharepoint designer workflow: condition on multiple choice field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

I am working on a workflow which is to send emails according a multichoice field.

He're my workflow-
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqkPO.png)

How can I change the workflow so that when BOTH items are selected it sends two emails to the different recipients?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use *if-else*, use 2 separate *IF's*, that should do what you want. e.g.

```
if(ChoiceControl contains 'Test Site')
  Email IT Support
if(ChoiceControl contains 'Thornleigh')
  Email Test
```

Comment: Just another question - would this work for SharePoint Designer 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Just below the first if, enter another 'if any value' Action and it will give you two joined if's joined by And. Change the And to Or. Here is an image that will show you the results.

[image]

Let me know in case you need further details.

Comment: Requirement is to send two separate emails to different email addresses if choice control contain both values. your workflow will send a single email if column contains 'any' of specified value.

Comment: Yeah, and the two emails can be place under the two joined if statements. That's just a screenshot of one of my workflows just to show its possible to join two if statements. But ideally more that one emailing actions can be placed under the two joined ifs.

Comment: why would you use joined conditions? unless it's required NOT to send an email in case of a certain value.

Comment: So that its cleaner and done on just one line. You could check several conditions on just one line.